# bash autocompletion filetype filter bypass

Tags: bash, autocomplete

How to ignore bash autocompletion's file filtering when it's broken?

For example, I want to auto complete a `iso` file for `bsdtar`, but my distro didn't include that extension. Pressing `tab` just feel like I'm in the wrong path, which is maddening.

Is there a way to make 4 or more tabs to autocomplete any file, regardless of rules?

I do not want to abandon bash completion but I also do not want to spend 3h hunting down files every time it behaves badly.